# Sufficient rigor in proving $f(x)$ is continuous at the origin, for $f$ analog to the Dirichlet function.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity

Let $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ be a function given by:

$$
f(x)=\begin{cases}
2x,&x\in\mathbb{Q}\\
-2x,&x\in\mathbb{I}\end{cases}
$$

$f(x)$ is continuous at the origin $0$.

---

Proof:

$\lim \limits_{x\to 0} 2x=\lim \limits_{x\to 0} -2x = 0$ and hence regardless of rationality or not, $f(0)=0$.

---

Is this rigorous?

Comment: A proof by definition would be more rigorous.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it's not sufficiently rigorous: either you make an $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ proof or appeal to a known theorem.

For instance, you can observe that
$$
|f(x)|\le|2x|
$$
and appeal to the squeeze theorem.

---

For an $\varepsilon$-$\delta$ proof, consider $\varepsilon>0$ and set $\delta=\varepsilon/2$. If $0<x<\delta$, we have two cases: either $x$ is rational, so $|f(x)-0|=|2x|=2|x|<2\delta=\varepsilon$, or $x$ is irrational, so $|f(x)-0|=|-2x|=2|x|<2\delta=\varepsilon$.

You can see that it's not really different from the “squeeze theorem” proof.

Comment: Or given an $\epsilon>0$, use the above inequality to find a $\delta > 0$ such that...

Comment: @Arthur Of course!

Comment: Sufficiently rigorous for what? If a function $f:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ is defined piecewise by $g:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ and $h:\Bbb R\to\Bbb R$ on some subsets of $\Bbb R$, and $g$ and $h$ both tend to $a$ as $x\to0$, then $f\to a$ as $x\to0$ as well. It is just a matter of whether you use this theorem or the squeeze theorem.

Comment: @Regret The question is exactly that: one should appeal to some general theorem or do a direct proof as suggested by Arthur. Indeed, I used “can”, not “must”.

Comment: @egreg: I would then mention "No, it's not sufficiently rigorous, because you have not referred to any theorem." The OP's proof is just short of saying "this implies the wanted result," which could very well be omitted because it is taken for granted.

Comment: @egreg: I was just afraid that first sentence in your answer could lead someone to believe that the theorem I mentioned in my first comment is false. $+1$.

Comment: I am just assuming now, but think OP just tries to have some sort of "perfect" proof, perfect as in: One who reads it, can immediately the problem as solved, but also keep it as short as possible with no content of any unnecessary information.. Therefore I would side with egreg and Arthur and say OP's proof is too short / insufficient as such.

Comment: How can I prove that the limit exists at $x=0$ using $\epsilon-\delta$?

Comment: @Analysis I added it

Answer (score 3):

First of all, your conclusion should not be that $f(0)=0$, it should be that $\lim_{x\to 0} f(x) = 0$.

Your proof isn't really rigorous, although the idea is correct. What you're implicitly assuming is something like the following proposition:

> If $\lim_{x\to a} g(x) = L$ and $\lim_{x\to a} h(x) = L$, and if
>    $$f(x)=\begin{cases}
> g(x),&x\in A\\
> h(x),&x\in \mathbb R \setminus A\end{cases}$$
>   Then $\lim_{x\to a} f(x) = L$.

Which is true, but you should at the very least state it explicitly even if you don't take the time to prove it, otherwise your proof seems like an appeal to intuition.

Comment: How can I prove that the limit exists at $x=0$ using $\epsilon-\delta$?

Comment: @Analysis Fix $\epsilon$. Then there exists a $\delta_1$ that works for $g$ and a $\delta_2$ that works for $h$. The smaller of the two works as the $\delta$ for $f$.